# replace parameter name with value in url

Tags: .htaccess

I have spent time trying to manipulate my .htaccess file and searching around to get this done, I want to be able to allow `mywebsite.com/911` to be understood by my  php script as a GET parameter `mywebsite.com/?phone=911`.

I have tried several codes such as:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/$ /index.php?phone=$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Unfortunately it gives `404` same as with all the snippets i tried from similar questions.

Your kind help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finally with a working code:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /index.php?phone=$1 [L,QSA]
```